# Manage multiple callbacks

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface

I have made a user interface with many *edit text* boxes created in loops, now I want to store the user inputs in a variable with *callback*.

For example consider this code,

```
function p = myfun()
f = figure;
set(f,'Position',[200 350 250 150],'Color',[.4 .6 .4],'MenuBar','none',...
    'Visible','off');
bc = [.4 .6 .4];
uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 80 80 30],...
        'String','X','BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');
uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 40 80 30],...
        'String','Y','BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');
uicontrol('style','edit','Position', [120 80 80 30],...
    'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w','Callback',{@My_Callback});
uicontrol('style','edit','Position', [120 40 80 30],...
    'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w','Callback',{@My_Callback});
uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Ok',...
    'Position', [100 5 60 30],'Callback', 'close'); 
movegui(f,'center')
set(f,'Visible','on')

function My_Callback(hObject,eventdata)
    p = str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
end
end
```

[image]

Now `My_Callback` will be called twice but only the last one will be stored in `p`.

But I want them to be stored like `p.x` and `p.y`.

I think I should use `Tag`, it says:

`Tag`

`string (GUIDE sets this property)`

`User-specified object label. The Tag property provides a means to identify graphics objects with a user-specified label. This is particularly useful when constructing interactive graphics programs that would otherwise need to define object handles as global variables or pass them as arguments between callback routines. You can define Tag as any string.`

But I don't know how (I have about 16 editable boxes),

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When do you want to read values from editbox, immediately after they were entered, or after the button "Ok" pressed?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin, after the `ok` was pressed because user might change them. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use the `UserData` property of `uicontrols` to store the content of the edit boxes as you enter it, that way it would be very easy to recover them anywhere within your GUI or elsewhere.

Moreover, to facilitate things you can assign names to uicontrols during their creation, so when you need to get one/many of their property you can call the handles with its name instead of the `hObject` argument.

For example, let's say you name the box with the X data `x1`, then you can create and store it in the handles structure of the GUI like so:

```
handles.x1 = uicontrol(...)
```

so when you need to fetch a property, you can use

```
get(handles.x1,'Some Property');
```

So to come back to your question, you could use this syntax to set the `UserData` property of all the boxes inside `My_Callback`. Afterward you can recover them in any callback you want. Of course a simple way would be to get the `String` property of the edit boxes instead of their `UserData`, but with the latter you can store anything you want which might come handy.

In the following GUI I modified yours to change the callback for the 'OK' button for a function called `DisplayData` which gets the `UserData` from each edit box and displays it.

```
function p = myfun()
clear
clc

f = figure;
set(f,'Position',[200 350 250 150],'Color',[.4 .6 .4],'MenuBar','none',...
    'Visible','off');
bc = [.4 .6 .4];
%//===============
uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 80 80 30],...
    'String','X','BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');

uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 40 80 30],...
    'String','Y','BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');
%//===============

handles.x1 = uicontrol('style','edit's,'Position', [120 80 80 30],...
    'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w','Callback',{@My_Callback});

handles.y1 = uicontrol('style','edit','Position', [120 40 80 30],...
    'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w','Callback',{@My_Callback});
%//===============
uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Ok',...
    'Position', [100 5 60 30],'Callback', @(s,e) DisplayData);

movegui(f,'center')
set(f,'Visible','on')

guidata(f,handles); %// Updata guidata

    function My_Callback(hObject,eventdata)

        p = str2double(get(hObject,'string'));

        %// Assign the content of the box to its "UserData" property
        set(hObject,'UserData',p)
        guidata(f,handles)
    end

    function DisplayData(~,~)


        %// You could do it for all the boxes in your GUI.
       x1Data = get(handles.x1,'UserData');
       y1Data = get(handles.y1,'UserData');

       fprintf('The number in box 1 is %0.2f and the number in box 2 is %0.2f\n',x1Data,y1Data);

       guidata(f,handles)
    end
end
```

Sample output:

[image]

And after pressing the "OK" button, this string is displayed in the Command Window:

```
The number in box 1 is 2.00 and the number in box 2 is 4.00
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome then glad to help!

Comment: What are the inputs for `DisplayData`?

Comment: Actually they are not strictly necessary and it's a habit of mine, but I read somewhere some time ago that in some cases anonymous functions required at least 2 input arguments to avoid errors about incorrect # of input/output arguments (I wish I still had the source) so it became a habit to always call them like so.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in comments, you want to read your values from editbox after the "Ok" button pressed. In order to do this, you should assign your callback function to the "ok" button, not edit boxes:

```
uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Ok',...
'Position', [100 5 60 30],'Callback', {@My_Callback});
```

In your Callback function you should read values from all your edit boxes.

I suggest you to use handles when you defined your edit boxes (and better to use it for all the objects):

```
 e1=uicontrol('style','edit','Position', [120 80 80 30],...
'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');
e2=uicontrol('style','edit','Position', [120 40 80 30],...
'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');
```

Now, in order to read values, you just use handles of the corresponding edit box.

```
function My_Callback(hObject,eventdata)
    p1 = str2double(get(e1,'string'));
    p2 = str2double(get(e2,'string'));
end
```

Note: this handles (`e1`,`e2`) will have cyan color in your code, that means that they are "global" variables, i.e. are used in main code and callback function.

If you don't want to use global handles, you can pass them into callback function. So your callback function will have more arguments.

```
uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Ok',...
'Position', [100 5 60 30],'Callback', {@My_Callback(e1,e2)});

function My_Callback(hObject,eventdata,e1,e2)
    p1 = str2double(get(e1,'string'));
    p2 = str2double(get(e2,'string'));
end
```

Comment: I just edited my answer: you shouldn't use callback functions for edit boxes.

Comment: Thanks, good point in defining callback for the button. I have the boxes defined in a loop let me see if I can handle that.